# Foundation top-bar isn't working

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to use foundation to build a navigation menu. The black bar loads with my content, but some features don't work. For example, the drop down menu doesn't work when the mouse hovers over it. Also the proper mouseover effects arent working. Am I forgetting something?

http://jsfiddle.net/Sbt75/755/

Here is my code

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    <!--Jquery-->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--Foundation-->
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css" type="text/css" />


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div class="contain-to-grid sticky">
        <nav class="top-bar" role="navigation" data-options="is_hover: true">
            <ul class="title-area">
                <li class="name">
                    <h1><a href="#">VoIP Innovations</a></h1>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <section class="top-bar-section">
                <ul class="left">
                    <li class="has-dropdown">
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="#">Origination</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Termination</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">E911</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Hosted Billing</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Nav 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Nav 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Nav 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Nav 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </nav>
        </div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        $(document).foundation();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5q09ajx/).

Firstly, you have to put `data-topbar` attribute into your `nav` element.

Secondly, you have to put `li` with menu into your code:

```
<li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon">
   <a href="#">
      <span>Menu</span>
   </a>
</li>
```

Whole HTML:

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation" data-options="is_hover: true">
   <ul class="title-area">
      <li class="name">
         <h1>
            <a href="#">VoIP Innovations</a>
         </h1>
      </li>
      <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon">
         <a href="#">
            <span>Menu</span>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <section class="top-bar-section">
      <ul class="left">
         <li class="has-dropdown">
            <a href="#">Services</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
               <li>
                  <a href="#">Origination</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#">Termination</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#">E911</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#">Hosted Billing</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#">Nav 2</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#">Nav 3</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#">Nav 4</a>
         </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#">Nav 5</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </section>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think you are missing one atribute, before role="navigation" on the nav tag, add data-topbar

so it would look like this

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation" data-options="is_hover: true">
```

Haven't found anything else missing

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way that the foundation documents use:

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
```

Try changing your nav tag out with this and let me know what happens.

Comment: Ok so this fixed the hover issue. However, the links still disappear when the nav bar gets small.

Comment: Do you mean that they're not showing up when you click the menu button (should be on the right) when your viewport gets small?

Comment: The menu button doesnt show up at all when the viewport gets small.

Comment: Try putting your foundation css import after the normalize import!